# Changing user data in django python

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

guys! I'm new to django and I'm developing simple web site with user registration. I want to test some things, for example: on user profile page I added picture:

[image]

and by pressing on it picture should change to:

[image]

And by pressing on red one it should be changed to grey.
Condotion of this picture should be saved. I have seven pictures for every day of the week and user should be able to change every picture.

I've created a model like this (if you have any better ideas it would be great):

```
 class Week1(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     utr_ust0 = models.IntegerField(default=0, max_length=3)
     utr_ust1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, max_length=3)
     utr_ust2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, max_length=3)
     ...
```

utr_ust0 = 0 (grey)
utr_ust0 = 1 (red)

But I cant't really understand how to work with this model in views. I think that during registration I should do something like this:

```
auth.login(request, user)
Week1.objects.create(utr_ust0=0, utr_ust1=0, utr_ust2=0, utr_ust3=0,
             utr_ust4=0, utr_ust5=0, utr_ust6=0, user_id=username)
```

But I get this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test5'`

And in the function that loads page with the calendar I'm returning dict like this:

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        content['smiles'] = [Week1.utr_ust0, Week1.utr_ust1, Week1.utr_ust2,
                         Week1.utr_ust3, Week1.utr_ust4, Week1.utr_ust5, Week1.utr_ust6]
```

And of course I should add some ajax script but I dont' now yet how to do this.
Any ideas or advices? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
...utr_ust6=0, user_id=username)
```

user_id should be a user ID, an int, or pass the object:

```
week1.objects.create(..., user=user)
```

check the type of `user` in `auth.login(..)` or pick it from the request if it's available: `request.user`

Comment: Now I get this error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'`

Comment: because you have to write `,.....user=user)`, and you probably wrote `user_id=user)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can I ask one more question, how to return information about the user who requested the page properly? I thought I can do it like this: `content['smiles'] = [Week1.utr_ust0, ...` but it's stupid way

Comment: I think that second question is rather broad. you could use any of the `render()` shortcuts (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render), or an API. it's hard to say. you can make a new question with the specifics and accept this one.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `render()` for most of my functions and right now I'm returning `content` dict in render. But, I mean, how can I return from Model `Week1` data about user `test`. Won't `Week1.utr_ust0` return array with information about all users?

Comment: the orm has the inverse set for all relations. `user.week1_set.all()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/